# Circular dependency in pip/virtualenv installation instructions?

Tags: linux, python

This may be obvious to everyone else, and I'm just over-thinking things, but here goes anyways. It's obviously not completely circular, but the recommended path seems so.

Since this has gotten really long, I'll start with my suggestion. If you start at the virtualenv docs, the first suggestion should be a failsafe way to install virtualenv without pip or anything else that might be missing from the distro ('curl virtualenv_setup | python?). If you start at the pip docs, the first suggestion should be how to install virtualenv normally, not a non-root workaround.

---

**virtualenv**

So the goal is to I'll start with whatever ancient version of python is included with my distro, and get the latest versions of pip and virtualenv, ideally with a clear and simple upgrade path for each.

I'll start with virtualenv, from [the docs](http://virtualenv.org/en/latest.html#installation)

> You can install virtualenv with `pip install virtualenv`, or the latest development version with `pip install virtualenv==dev`.

The whole point is that I don't have, so that's out. I'll keep reading...

> You can also use `easy_install` or if you have no Python package manager available at all, you can just grab the single file virtualenv.py and run it with `python virtualenv.py`.

easy_install happened to be the way I got things working, but lets say my distro wasn't kind enough to provide that. And grabbing virtualenv.py seems like a good temporary solution, but not a long term one.

---

**pip**

OK, so how about we try starting with pip? from [the docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#installation-instructions):

> The recommended way to use pip is within virtualenv, since every virtualenv has pip installed in it automatically. This does not require root access or modify your system Python installation. For instance:

Hoo boy. Again, simply downloading virtualenv.py is to me a temporary solution, and undesirable on systems I *do* have root access to.

> Prior to installing pip make sure you have either setuptools or distribute installed

OK, so to install a package manager, I first need to install some other installation helper? Is this just for the purposes of installing or are they dependencies that have to stick around? In any case, installing from curl is pretty neat(1).

> Download get-pip.py and execute it, using the Python interpreter of your choice:

Neat, another curl-install. This gives me a pip for my distro's version of python, and allows me to get virtualenv for it, which then gives me a separate pip per env. I think? Since I already have things set up, I can't try this method to see what it does.

---

(1) Out of curiosity, I checked on the recommended way to install distribute. Fortunately, it is basically this curl method. You could use pip, though!

Comment: "And grabbing virtualenv.py seems like a good temporary solution, but not a long term one"  Why not?  If your distro doesn't provide what you want as packages, then you must manage them manually or choose another distro.  You just have to decide which of pip, easy_install or virtualenv you want to manage yourself if you want to stick with your dist.

Comment: Maybe I'm weird, but I don't like manually copying things to /usr, nor installing to ~/bin unless i have to. I guess it seems to me like a package manager at least should be able take care of itself. Maybe things will get better when major distros finally include pip/virtualenv by default (it's not like on some 10-user distro), because I can't recall having any major problems with CPAN (not that perl doesn't have problems, the 5/6 issue is the same as py's 2/3). Maybe Zed had a point when he said distros have killed python

Comment: But what distribution doesn't have easy_install (which you could kick everything off from)?  This is the equivilen of CPAN.

Comment: I don't know enough about different distros or when easy_install came out or how much out there is backwards-compatible. CPAN can update itself, but I just tried `easy_install easy_install` and got nothing. I certainly don't see anyone asking me to replace CPAN. I'm obviously new to the python community/ecosystem, but it seems like there are a few too many hoops for what I thought was a newbie-friendly language.

Comment: If your distribution has easy_install then its updates would be managed by the package manager, not by easy_install itself.  I think you are looking for behaviour equivilences in CPAN that are unnecessary.  Install easy_install, use that to install virtualenv, use that to install pip.  I am voting to close this as there doesn't appear to be an issue to solve.

Comment: That explanation actually makes sense. It's what I had done, but I wasn't sure it was the "right" thing to do, and needed assurance that using the semi-deprecated easy_install was an OK way to kick things off. If you post that as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yeah deprecated but still pretty active - I get your reluctance.  Before we move to an answer, what dist are you choosing?  The ones I am familiar with have easy_install, virtualenv, and pip all available and maintained in their respective package manager

Comment: Right now I'm on Crunchbang, which AFAICT, uses Debian Squeeze's package management system for most things, including it virtualenv (although it's incompatible with 2.7), and python-pip, but I don't see a 'supported' icon next to it in synaptic. I think easy_install must have come from the 'python' package, since there's no separate entry for it.